# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80045003

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, speech-recognition

I am using C#.Net to develop the Speech recognition engine to develop speech to text in Bangla. I have tried several times to load the grammar file to the speech engine.
But it shows me the error. How I can resolve this problem?

My XML grammar loading code is

```
grammar.CmdLoadFromFile(appPath + FileName, SpeechLib.SpeechLoadOption.SLOStatic);
//grammar.CmdLoadFromFile("E:\\Speech RecognitionByp\\SpeechRecognitionByp@bengaliGramme.xml",SpeechLib.SpeechLoadOption.SLODynamic);
grammar.CmdSetRuleIdState(0, SpeechRuleState.SGDSActive);
```

Answer (score 3):

The error means [SPERR_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - this can only be resolved by correcting the format of your file...

Comment: glad I could help - please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted when an answer was helpful.